# How can I run two screens from two separate GPUs?

Tags: nvidia, graphics, xorg, multiple-monitors

I have two nVidia GTS 450 GPUs, each with a DVI, an HDMI and a VGA port. I want two screens, both running off the DVI ports.

I've setup my `xorg.conf` file in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` but it is not working.

```
xorg.conf
```

```
# nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings
# nvidia-settings:  version 361.42  (buildd@lgw01-18)  Tue Apr  5 14:33:28 UTC 2016

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "Module"
    Load           "dbe"
    Load           "extmod"
    Load           "type1"
    Load           "freetype"
    Load           "glx"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Acer S220HQL"
    HorizSync       31.0 - 83.0
    VertRefresh     56.0 - 76.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTS 450"
    BusID          "PCI:1:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-0"
    Option         "metamodes" "GPU-661ea8ef-0beb-0b79-5958-62e5a84fb2f5.DVI-I-1: nvidia-auto-select +0+0, GPU-93c7ee63-95cd-dd42-a64e-d669451a0150.DVI-I-1: nvidia-auto-select +1920+0"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "SLI" "off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "on"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

It would appear that nVidia is ignoring my xorg file - as when I open the X Server settings program, I see the following:

[image]

Base mosaic turns itself off, and the second screen is disabled.

I'm running Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 and I have nVidia drivers installed, version `361-updates`.

How can I get nVidia to recognise my `xorg.conf` file, and to have two screens on two cards?

Comment: you mean multiseat ? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MultiseatX or https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Multiseat

Comment: @bodhi.zazen No - I just want two screens, one on each GPU - a dual screen setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So uhh... This is a little embarrassing... I uhh my umm. Okay. I'll say it. My SLI cord came undone.

[image]

I have got it working now. Although I also had to change my xorg file from using DPF-0 screen to DVI-I-0.

Yep.